# series.sum() give NaN result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The following table show  transactions between two users, I need to find the  the change in net worth for each user.

[image]

I used following code, but it give be incorrect result for user 4 & 5

```
credit = ts.groupby('sender').sum()
debit = ts.groupby('receiver').sum()
net_change = debit - credit
net_change
```

[image]

Comment: becasue `credit` has index of `1,2,3,5` and `debit` has index of `1,2,3,4`, as `4,5` are not the common index in  `credit`  and  `debit`. you can use `debit.subtract(credit, fill_value=0)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

You can use pandas' DataFrame.subtract to subtract dataframe where you can specify what value to fill if same index aren't available on both dataframe

```
credit = ts.groupby('sender').sum()
debit = ts.groupby('receiver').sum()
net_change = debit.subtract(credit, fill_value=0)
net_change
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html

Comment: Hi Gopal, thanks for quick response. The reset_index() does not solve problem. I am still not able to get the net worth for receiver 5  which is $-10

Comment: I have updated my answer. This should work for you